# How do I convert a multiple paged PDF into a PNG image per pdf page in Python

Tags: python, pdf, png, image-conversion, pdf2image

Amateur Python developer here.  I'm working on a project where I take multiple PDfs, each one with varying amounts of pages(1-20ish), and turn them into PNG files to use with pytesseract later.

I'm using pdf2image and poppler on a test pdf that has 3 pages.  The problem is that it only converts the last page of the PDF to a PNG.  I thought "maybe the program is making the same file name for each pdf page, and with each iteration it rewrites the file until only the last pdf page remains" So I tried to write the program so it would change the file name with each iteration.  Here's the code.

```
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
images = convert_from_path('/Users/jacobpatty/vscode_projects/badger_colors/test_ai/10254_Craigs_Plumbing.pdf', 200)

file_name = 'ping_from_ai_test.png'
file_number = 0
for image in images:
    file_number =+ 1
    file_name = 'ping_from_ai_test' + str(file_number) + '.png'
    image.save(file_name)
```

This failed in 2 ways. It only made 2 png files('ping_from_ai_test.png' and 'ping_from_ai_test1.png') instead of 3, and when I clicked on the png files they were both just the last pdf page again.  I don't know what to do at this point, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is only outputting a single file as far as I can see. The problem is that you have a typo in your code.

The line

`file_number =+ 1`

is actually an assignment:

`file_number = (+1)`

This should probably be

`file_number += 1`

Answer (score 1):

try this instead of doing for image in images:

```
for n in range(len(images)):
    images[n].save('test' + str(n) + '.png')
```

Does that work?